# How to use terminal commands with Github?

Tags: git, github

I have forked a private repository (an iPhone project) as follows:

```
cd nameofdirectory
git init
git clone forkedURL
```

Now I want to push the changes done by me to my forked repository so that the main admin can review my written code and merge it with the main repository.

How can I push the changes done by me to my forked repository using terminal on MacOS?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can't push into other people's repositories. This is because push permanently gets code into their repository, which is not cool.

What you should do, is to *ask them* to pull from your repository. This is done in GitHub by going to the other repository and sending a "pull request".

There is a very informative article on the GitHub's help itself: https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests

---

To interact with your own repository, you have the following commands. I suggest you start reading on Git a bit more for these instructions (lots of materials online).

To add new files to the repository or add changed files to staged area:

```
$ git add <files>
```

To commit them:

```
$ git commit
```

To commit unstaged but changed files:

```
$ git commit -a
```

To push to a repository (say `origin`):

```
$ git push origin
```

To push only one of your branches (say `master`):

```
$ git push origin master
```

To fetch the contents of another repository (say `origin`):

```
$ git fetch origin
```

To fetch only one of the branches (say `master`):

```
$ git fetch origin master
```

To merge a branch with the current branch (say `other_branch`):

```
$ git merge other_branch
```

Note that `origin/master` is the name of the branch you fetched in the previous step from `origin`. Therefore, updating your master branch from origin is done by:

```
$ git fetch origin master
$ git merge origin/master
```

You can read about all of these commands in their manual pages (either on your linux or online), or follow the GitHub helps:

- https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo for commit and push
- https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo for fetch and merge

Comment: Hi Shahbaj  well i asked how to push changes to my personal forked repo and not to some other people`s repo :-)

Answer (score 12):

```
git add myfile.h
git commit -m "your commit message"
git push -u origin master
```

if you don't remember all the files you need to update, use

```
git status
```

Comment: Thanks Morgan....Suppose the file name where changes in code are done is myfile.h then is the following correct:                  git add myfile.h 
git commit -m "your commit message"
git push -u origin master

Comment: I've updated the example to include your filename. You can also repeat the "git add" for each file before doing the other two.

Comment: Also, be sure to write a summary of what you've changed in the file where I put "your commit message".

Comment: actually I was missing the first step.....will check these three steps shortly....also could you please tell me how to update my code with the changes made in the main repository...

Comment: @Priyanshu, seems like you need to start learning git from a good tutorial. Looking at the helps in GitHub itself is a great start. In response to your previous comment, what you need is a `git fetch origin` followed by `git merge origin/master` (but don't blindly follow what I said)

Comment: Thanks, VOTE UP! that was the only thing that solved the "did not match any file s known to git" on xcode.

Answer (score 1):

To add all file at a time, use **`git add -A`**

To check git whole status, use **`git log`**